Why isn't the turbo frame loading content from the turbo frame referenced in the source
I am trying to implement turbo frames to get my navbar to load via a turbo frame. Have installed using:
Add the turbo-rails gem to your Gemfile: gem 'turbo-rails'
Run ./bin/bundle install
Run ./bin/rails turbo:install

My routes:
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get "/", to: "marketing#index"
  get "nav", to: "components#nav"
end

gems:
gem 'rails', '~> 7.2.0'
gem "propshaft"
gem 'puma'
gem "jsbundling-rails"
gem "cssbundling-rails"
gem "jbuilder"

gem "nokogiri"
gem 'turbo-rails'

marketing/index.html.erb:
<body class="body">

  <div id="nav_bar">
    <%= turbo_frame_tag "nav_bar", src: nav_path do %>
    <% end%>
  </div>

...
</body>

components/nav.html.erb
<%= turbo_frame_tag "nav_bar" do %>
  <div class="hybrid-nav" id="nav_bar">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>

components_controller.rb
class ComponentsController < ApplicationController
  def nav
    byebug
  end
end

When visiting the marketing index route with the turbo frame tag in the view, it's not even hitting the components controller nav method. If I visit /nav the navbar loads fine
I'm sure I've missed something really obvious - can anyone help?

Did you try using the browser console to debug it? You can't approach JS issues solely from the backend.

are you running bin/dev?

Your app might not be sending the turbo javascript library to the browser.
I would suggest checking your app/assets/builds/application.js to see if you have bundled your javascript assets. If it only contains the following:
//# sourceMappingURL=/assets/application.js.map

...then you may need to run bin/rails javascript:build (or run bin/rails assets:precompile) to build your JS bundle.
